# Beginner Question: How to close/split panels?

Tags: interface

I can't figure out how to close or split windows or panels in 2.8. In videos, to remove a panel it seems you somehow click in the upper right corner-doesn't work for me. To split a panel you somehow drag from the border and a new window appears. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Rusty

Comment: thank you! That did it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the mouse pointer too, as you probably saw in those videos. Move the cursor around the corner of one of two equally sized adjacent panels, when it becomes a cross.

Then click and keep the mouse button pressed, then drag up/down (to join panels vertically) or left/right (to join panels horizontally), see the animation below for some examples:

[image]

As you see, you can also split panels in this way: just start the dragging from a panel and move inward, that panel will split in two.

Comment: awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hover over the edge between two windows and right click. It should bring up a Area Options menu.